# MySQL stored procedure to return table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to return data from a table. I'm using MySQL.
this is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`imswms`@`10.0.90.%` FUNCTION `sp_daily_numbers_by_man_and_prod`(`man` VARCHAR(100), `startDate` DATETIME, `endDate` DATETIME)
RETURNS SET
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
select * from dailynumbersdetails 
 where dailynumbersdetails.PostDate >= startDate 
    and dailynumbersdetails.PostDate < endDate 
    and dailynumbersdetails.Manufacturer = man 
    group by dailynumbersdetails.PartNumber;
END
```

But when trying to save the procedure I get the following error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LANGUAGE SQL  NOT DETERMINISTIC   READS SQL DATA  SQL SECURITY DEFINER    COMME' at line 3

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax was incorrect. You created a FUNCTION, but needed to create a PROCEDURE that returns result set. Try this code -

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'imswms'@'10.0.90.%'
PROCEDURE `sp_daily_numbers_by_man_and_prod` (`man` VARCHAR(100), `startDate` DATETIME, `endDate` DATETIME)
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM dailynumbersdetails
  WHERE dailynumbersdetails.PostDate >= startDate
  AND dailynumbersdetails.PostDate < endDate
  AND dailynumbersdetails.Manufacturer = man
  GROUP BY dailynumbersdetails.PartNumber;
END
```